# save excel file stream to azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, openpyxl

I programmed a few lines of code in Python which opens an Excel file from a Azure Blob Storage with the openpyxl-library. The code is running in Azure Functions.

After a few modifications on the content, I will create a second workbook and copy the content from the original workbook into it. I saved the second workbook as a stream.
Now I want to save the second workbook back to the blob storage as an Excel file again (other container).

```
    import logging
    from typing import Container
    
    import azure.functions as func
    import azure.storage.blob
    import openpyxl as xl
    import io
    

    ### Start Trigger
    def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
        logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                     f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                     f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
        logging.info('Loading Workbook...')
        ### Load Excel file
        wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=io.BytesIO(myblob.read()))
        logging.info(wb1.sheetnames)
        
        ### Create Second Workbook
        output = io.BytesIO()
        wb2 = xl.Workbook()
        wb2.active
        wb2.create_sheet('TestSheet')
        wb2.save(output)

        ### Upload to Azure Blob Storage
        blob_service_client = azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conString)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='test2', blob='test2.xlsx')
        blob_client.upload_blob(output)
```

When I now run the code everything will work. But the excel file is corrupt on the blob storage and I get the following error when I try to open the Excel file:
[image]

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here: `wb2.save(output)`, you can refer to the following code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.storage.blob
import openpyxl as xl
import io
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    #logging.info(myblob.read())
    logging.info('Loading Workbook...')
    ### Load Excel file
    wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=io.BytesIO(myblob.read()))
    ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
    logging.info(wb1.sheetnames)

    ### Create Second Workbook
    #output = io.BytesIO()
    wb2 = xl.Workbook()
    ws2 = wb2.create_sheet('TestSheet')

    # calculate total number of rows and 
    # columns in source excel file
    mr = ws1.max_row
    mc = ws1.max_column
    
    # copying the cell values from source 
    # excel file to destination excel file
    for i in range (1, mr + 1):
        for j in range (1, mc + 1):
            # reading cell value from source excel file
            c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
    
            # writing the read value to destination excel file
            ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value

    ### Upload to Azure Blob Storage
    conString = ""
    blob_service_client = azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conString)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='testout', blob='test2.xlsx')
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
        wb2.save(tmp.name)
        output = io.BytesIO(tmp.read())
        blob_client.upload_blob(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when I try your solution I get the following error:

`System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTriggerDev1. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptc75e7gh'`

Comment: Maybe you can change another temporary path. During the test, I found that saving to the stream will cause your problem. You can save it locally and then upload it to storage.

Comment: Is it possible to store locally a file when I run the code in Azure Functions?

Comment: Try this code: `temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()    file_path = os.path.join(temp_path, 'output.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is coming back to this like me. For me it worked that way (using the `getvalue()` function):

```
output = BytesIO()
wb2.save(output)
blob_client.upload_blob(output.getvalue())
```